# Do I need to handle any error cases in my code below?

Tags: c++, file, error-handling

My code writes to file as below. Do I need to worry about any error cases?
Do I need to handle the following error cases?

1.Logical error on i/o operation,

2.Read/writing error on i/o operation,

3.Exception safety.

If yes, how can I do it and if not, is it safe?

```
char command[150]={0};

 sprintf(command, "/mypath/mycommand > %s", FileName);

 system(command);
```

Comment: Yes you should always check for error if you call functions that can fail. But (for this case using `system`) unless the command you attempt to run returns specific error code for specific errors in the command itself, all you will know is if the command ran or not. It is not a C++ function as such, and therefore won't throw exceptions.

Comment: Also, the [`sprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) function can theoretically fail as well. It's seldom enough that few ever check for error from it, not even experienced programmers. I do recommend using `snprintf` instead through, to lessen the risk of buffer overflow. Or use [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).

Comment: 1st you can check existence of file itself. Second, exception handlings is must during I/O operation. But you have to do work by yourself. We can give pointers but can do you work meant to be done by you.

Comment: yes i am checking the return value of system call but i am more curious to know about the file

Answer (score 2):

`command` probably be overflow if FileName is looooooooooooong. And `system(3)` return -1 on error

See `man 3 system`

> The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.   fork(2)  failed),  and  the
>   return  status  of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
>   in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command
>   will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
>   the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).
>
> If the value of command is NULL, system() returns non-zero if the shell
>   is available, and zero if not.
>
> system() does not affect the wait status of any other children.

Maybe the output file should be removed if error occured.

Answer (score 0):

A general rule of thumb that I follow is the Murphy's law: Anything that can go wrong will eventually go wrong. With this in mind, I always check for errors and exceptions unless there is a very good reason that checking for errors is unnecessary or redundant. However, these cases most also be kept to minimum.

In case of your code, I'd make the same recommendation: is it always safe to ignore the error codes of your code? Is there any specific action to do if the code encounters error? Looking at your code, I believe that there are few things that may go wrong (`mycommand` is deleted/moved/renamed by user, its execution permission is changed, etc.). Will any of these affect the rest of your program?